getting NoReverseMatch error even after correct urls and views
getting the error message of NoReversedMatch even after creating path in urls.py and function in views.py
when i type url manually its working properly so the path is not wrong pleaze someone help me
NoReverseMatch at /mcq_web/
Reverse for 'quizes' not found. 'quizes' is not a valid view function or pattern name.

the html where it is giving error is
href = "{% url 'quizes' quiz_type.id %}"

here is my urls.py
from django.contrib import admin
from django.urls import path
from . import views

urlpatterns = [
    path('', views.show_quiz, name="quiz_show"),
    path('add/',views.add_user, name ="new user"),
    path('show_quiz/', views.show_quiz, name="quiz_types"),
    path('<int:quiz_type_id>/quizes/', views.quizes, name="ShortedQuizTypes"),
]

this is my views.py part to that error
def quizes(request,quiz_type_id):
    quiz_type = get_object_or_404( Quiz_types,pk = quiz_type_id)
    quizes = quiz_data.objects.all()
    quiz_types = Quiz_types.objects.all()
    details = {'quiz':quizes,'quiz_type':quiz_type,'quiz_types':quiz_types}
    return render(request,'shorted_show_quiz.html',{'details':details})



just in case this is my whole views.py
from django.shortcuts import render
from django.shortcuts import get_object_or_404
from .models import quiz_data,quiz,quiz_history,Quiz_types,options,user
from .forms import user_form 
# Create your views here.

# function to show quiz by type
def quizes(request,quiz_type_id):
    quiz_type = get_object_or_404( Quiz_types,pk = quiz_type_id)
    quizes = quiz_data.objects.all()
    quiz_types = Quiz_types.objects.all()
    details = {'quiz':quizes,'quiz_type':quiz_type,'quiz_types':quiz_types}
    return render(request,'shorted_show_quiz.html',{'details':details})


# function to add new users
def add_user(request):
    if request.method == 'POST':
        form = user_form(request.POST)
        if form.is_valid:
            form.save()


# function to show quiz by type
def show_quiz(request):
    quizes = quiz_data.objects.all()
    quiz_types = Quiz_types.objects.all()
    details = {'quiz':quizes,'quiz_types':quiz_types}
    return render(request,'show_quiz.html',{'details':details})

i tried clearing cache data(i have unapplied all migration before clearing cache) restarted server many times  by typing the url manually its working but not in the template it keeps throwing error what should i do i am stuck
here is the entire traceback
Environment:


Request Method: GET
Request URL: http://127.0.0.1:8000/mcq_web/

Django Version: 5.0.6
Python Version: 3.11.0
Installed Applications:
['django.contrib.admin',
 'django.contrib.auth',
 'django.contrib.contenttypes',
 'django.contrib.sessions',
 'django.contrib.messages',
 'django.contrib.staticfiles',
 'mcq_web']
Installed Middleware:
['django.middleware.security.SecurityMiddleware',
 'django.contrib.sessions.middleware.SessionMiddleware',
 'django.middleware.common.CommonMiddleware',
 'django.middleware.csrf.CsrfViewMiddleware',
 'django.contrib.auth.middleware.AuthenticationMiddleware',
 'django.contrib.messages.middleware.MessageMiddleware',
 'django.middleware.clickjacking.XFrameOptionsMiddleware']


Template error:
In template D:\gitrepo\user_login\mcq_web\templates\show_quiz.html, error at line 19
   Reverse for 'quizes' not found. 'quizes' is not a valid view function or pattern name.
   9 :       <ul class="nav nav-pills">
   10 :         <li class="nav-item"><a href="#" class="nav-link active" aria-current="page">Home</a></li>
   11 :         <li class="nav-item"><a href="#" class="nav-link">Quizes</a></li>
   12 :         <li class="nav-item"><a href="#" class="nav-link">Leaderboard</a></li>
   13 : 
   14 :       </ul>
   15 :     </header>
   16 :   </div>
   17 :   <div class="d-flex gap-2 justify-content-center py-5">
   18 :     {% for quiz_type in details.quiz_types %}
   19 :     <a class="btn btn-outline-secondary d-flex align-items-center" href = " {% url 'quizes' quiz_type.id %} " >
   20 :       {{quiz_type.type_name}}
   21 :       <svg class="bi ms-1" width="20" height="20"><use xlink:href="#arrow-right-short"></use></svg>
   22 :     </a>
   23 :   </div>
   24 :     {% endfor %}
   25 : {% endblock %}
   26 : 
   27 : 
   28 : {% block content %}
   29 : {% for quiz in details.quiz %}


Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "D:\gitrepo\.venv\Lib\site-packages\django\core\handlers\exception.py", line 55, in inner
    response = get_response(request)
               ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "D:\gitrepo\.venv\Lib\site-packages\django\core\handlers\base.py", line 197, in _get_response
    response = wrapped_callback(request, *callback_args, **callback_kwargs)
               ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "D:\gitrepo\user_login\mcq_web\views.py", line 29, in show_quiz
    return render(request,'show_quiz.html',{'details':details})
           ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "D:\gitrepo\.venv\Lib\site-packages\django\shortcuts.py", line 25, in render
    content = loader.render_to_string(template_name, context, request, using=using)
              ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "D:\gitrepo\.venv\Lib\site-packages\django\template\loader.py", line 62, in render_to_string
    return template.render(context, request)
           ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "D:\gitrepo\.venv\Lib\site-packages\django\template\backends\django.py", line 61, in render
    return self.template.render(context)
           ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "D:\gitrepo\.venv\Lib\site-packages\django\template\base.py", line 171, in render
    return self._render(context)
           ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "D:\gitrepo\.venv\Lib\site-packages\django\template\base.py", line 163, in _render
    return self.nodelist.render(context)
           ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "D:\gitrepo\.venv\Lib\site-packages\django\template\base.py", line 1000, in render
    return SafeString("".join([node.render_annotated(context) for node in self]))
                              ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "D:\gitrepo\.venv\Lib\site-packages\django\template\base.py", line 1000, in <listcomp>
    return SafeString("".join([node.render_annotated(context) for node in self]))
                               ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "D:\gitrepo\.venv\Lib\site-packages\django\template\base.py", line 961, in render_annotated
    return self.render(context)
           ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "D:\gitrepo\.venv\Lib\site-packages\django\template\loader_tags.py", line 159, in render
    return compiled_parent._render(context)
           ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "D:\gitrepo\.venv\Lib\site-packages\django\template\base.py", line 163, in _render
    return self.nodelist.render(context)
           ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "D:\gitrepo\.venv\Lib\site-packages\django\template\base.py", line 1000, in render
    return SafeString("".join([node.render_annotated(context) for node in self]))
                              ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "D:\gitrepo\.venv\Lib\site-packages\django\template\base.py", line 1000, in <listcomp>
    return SafeString("".join([node.render_annotated(context) for node in self]))
                               ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "D:\gitrepo\.venv\Lib\site-packages\django\template\base.py", line 961, in render_annotated
    return self.render(context)
           ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "D:\gitrepo\.venv\Lib\site-packages\django\template\loader_tags.py", line 65, in render
    result = block.nodelist.render(context)
             ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "D:\gitrepo\.venv\Lib\site-packages\django\template\base.py", line 1000, in render
    return SafeString("".join([node.render_annotated(context) for node in self]))
                              ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "D:\gitrepo\.venv\Lib\site-packages\django\template\base.py", line 1000, in <listcomp>
    return SafeString("".join([node.render_annotated(context) for node in self]))
                               ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "D:\gitrepo\.venv\Lib\site-packages\django\template\base.py", line 961, in render_annotated
    return self.render(context)
           ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "D:\gitrepo\.venv\Lib\site-packages\django\template\defaulttags.py", line 242, in render
    nodelist.append(node.render_annotated(context))
                    ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "D:\gitrepo\.venv\Lib\site-packages\django\template\base.py", line 961, in render_annotated
    return self.render(context)
           ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "D:\gitrepo\.venv\Lib\site-packages\django\template\defaulttags.py", line 479, in render
    url = reverse(view_name, args=args, kwargs=kwargs, current_app=current_app)
          ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "D:\gitrepo\.venv\Lib\site-packages\django\urls\base.py", line 88, in reverse
    return resolver._reverse_with_prefix(view, prefix, *args, **kwargs)
           ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "D:\gitrepo\.venv\Lib\site-packages\django\urls\resolvers.py", line 851, in _reverse_with_prefix
    raise NoReverseMatch(msg)
    ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^

Exception Type: NoReverseMatch at /mcq_web/
Exception Value: Reverse for 'quizes' not found. 'quizes' is not a valid view function or pattern name.



The name of the view is ShortedQuizTypes, not quizes, so:
<a href="{% url 'ShortedQuizTypes' quiz_type.id %}"></a>

Thanks it worked learned new thing today
